# How does the Firestore pricing work by big data?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

In my App the user can note his training in a table. So with the time the table (I use PaginatedDataTable for better performance) can get very big. I saw, that firestore offers 50.000 reads a day for free. Does every single data in the table stands for one read? In this case when the user have a big table with lets say 5.000 entrys, the 50.000 reads would be used very fast, especially when there are more users with much entrys.

Do I get this wrong or how does the counting work?

Comment: The pricing doesn't change at all based on the volume of data you're working with.  If you have further questions about billing that isn't covered in the documentation, you should direct those to Firebase support directly.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: Okay so what exactly happens when I open a table where is stored a lot of data in it. Does this count as one read?

Comment: Every document read is billed as one read.  It doesn't matter how many documents are in the collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time a document is read for your from the server, it counts as one document read. Running a query does **not** read all documents in the collection though, but only those that are returned by the query.

So if you read all 50,000 documents, that indeed counts as 50,000 document reads. But if you through a query reduce that number and read (say) only 100 documents from the 50,0000, then that only counts as 100 document read.

The only exception here is if a query returns no documents, it still is charged as 1 document read. Oh, and many of the SDKs (iOS, Android, Web) offer a client-side cache, and reads from the cache are of course also not charged.